# Can data from a sheet linked to a form merge into a google doc if form is re-submitted?

Tags: google-apps-script

Scenario: This is for music teachers checking out instruments. In a non-distance learning world, they would use a pre-made physical agreement form where parents would fill it out agreeing to keep the instrument safe. Name, Address, Phone, etc. are all on it. They are moving this form to a Google form and the district is allowing a typed out name from the parent to count in leu of a handwritten signature (yes, I am aware of add-ons that make handwritten possible, but, this is something that needs to be copied by other teachers and I do not want them to worry about downloading add ons). With the physical version, the parent fills it out, turns it in, and then the teacher fills in the serial number of the instrument being checked out to them along with their signature. Then, they give them back one the NCR color copies to the parent. Files away the top original.

Current Status:

- Form is done.
- It populates a google sheet.
- I found the following script that adds a link into one of the columns of that sheet that allows the teacher to go back into the form edit mode and add the district serial info and their “signature.” The then have to hit “submit” like the parent originally did. I also added a trigger (in the Edit > Current Project’s Triggers way) so that they happens automatically as a form is submitted.

  ```
    function autoFillGoogleDocFromForm(e) {

      var timestamp = e.values[0];
      var studentID = e.values[4];
      var studentFIRST = e.values[5];
      var studentLAST = e.values[6];
      var teacherSignature = e.values[19];
      var districtNumber = e.values[18];

      var file = DriveApp.getFileById('1nEEl6dcKTIZ5WZJDRdpD_ikuyupO58p5FgK5Yb63llc'); 


      var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById('18vUwzLCMt3nwephPC6KlyAVZ4wsfxZkF')
      var copy = file.makeCopy(studentLAST + ',' + studentFIRST, folder); 

      var doc = DocumentApp.openById(copy.getId()); 

      var body = doc.getBody(); 

    body.replaceText('{{ID}}', studentID); 
      body.replaceText('{{studentFirst}}', studentFIRST);  
      body.replaceText('{{studentLast}}', studentLAST); 
      body.replaceText('{{teacherSignature}} ', teacherSignature); 
      body.replaceText('{{districtNumber}}', districtNumber); 

      doc.saveAndClose(); 
    }
  ```
- That row of info is populated with the additional information from the teacher.

What I am hoping for:

- To have the information inputted in each row “mail merged” into a Google Doc that looks like the physical form we currently have. That way, it is easier for the respective teacher to PDF that doc back to the parent after they have filled out the teacher info either directly into the sheet or through the re-submit form method listed above.

Issues:

- I’m aware of the “On Edit” and “On Change” options in the trigger menu options. Neither work here.
- I’m ware of the “onEdit” script functionality, but, I do not know how to add it into the script above.
- I would prefer that this Google Doc’s creation is triggered by the teacher’s hitting of “Submit” rather than adding it in the google Sheet. The reason is, I want to avoid too many copies of the Google Doc to be made if the teacher somehow makes continuous mistakes, but, slowly enough to have the doc created between corrections. Having it done once they hit “Submit” seems to me to be the best way to avoid that.

Extra Credit:

- An automation to turn the Google Doc it creates into a PDF contained in the same folder. That way, the teacher can just send that and not worry about creating a PDF step.

Final, Ideal Workflow of all this:

1. Parent fill outs Google Form.
2. Teacher goes through the URL created from the script above and adds the info they need to add.
3. When the teacher hits submit, a Google Doc and/or a PDF is created where the info they and the parent have added has been merged into the pre-made template that is our current physical form.
4. Teacher finds that PDF and sends it back to the parent.

Comment: There is no onEdit or onChange() for Google Document.

Comment: This script is in the sheet, not the doc. This script does the merge. I just want to be able to have a way to either automate it for after the teacher goes back and adds their info OR if I could use a checkbox or something like that for each row to activate the merge.

Comment: Also, I didn't put this in the post, but, we are not requiring e-mails. So, any option to e-mail the parent back their own responses (or the one's added by the teacher) is not an option.

Comment: The onFormSubmit is in the linked sheets spreadsheet but it's accessing and document.  If you want to use an onEdit() or onChange Trigger you have have something to edit in a sheet so wheres the sheet that you want to edit and what do you want to do with it.  This question sounds like a wish list that you want us to do. While many of us will write scripts it's normally something that's  well defined and reasonably easy to debug and usually the question has to contain a complete attempt at the answer.  This question meets neither of those critieria.

Answer (score -2):

Have you tried using ready-made solutions like [airslate](https://www.airslate.com/) ?
As far as I know, they have all the automation functionality you need + integrated bots that can change the user's role depending on the type of form or document you opened